# Enqueue error on adding multiple values

Tags: c#

I am trying to enqueue values on to a queue and it works fine. When the program runs for few hours, I get the following error

```
System.ArgumentException: length
  at System.Array.Copy (System.Array sourceArray, System.Int32 sourceIndex, System.Array destinationArray, System.Int32 destinationIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x000c3] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T].SetCapacity (System.Int32 capacity) [0x0001e] in <ccafeb0e74bd436bb84e5138772c2bb0>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T].Enqueue (T item) [0x0003e] in <ccafeb0e74bd436bb84e5138772c2bb0>:0 
  at VSCaptureMP.MPudpclient.ExportWaveToCSV () [0x0010a] in <f1c552d4f5b3424d9438ec1100580a9d>:0 
  at VSCaptureMP.MPudpclient.PollPacketDecoder (System.Byte[] packetbuffer, System.Int32 headersize) [0x00121] in <f1c552d4f5b3424d9438ec1100580a9d>:0
```

I am enqueuing values every hundred millisecond and I have a task which dequeues from the queue. The queue is not increasing and its count lies between 250 and 500. What could be the issue? I tried ConcurrentQueue as well. The program then ran longer though but after 12 hours it gave the following exception:

```
at (wrapper alloc) System.Object.AllocVector(intptr,intptr) 
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue1+Segment[T]..ctor (System.Int32 boundedLength) [0x00006] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0 
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue1[T].EnqueueSlow (T item) [0x00051] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0 
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[T].Enqueue (T item) [0x00010] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0
```

Comment: Post your code! Queues don't throw when you add entries even in a tight loop. 500 is a *tiny* amount of data. On the other hande `Queue<T>` is *NOT* thread-safe and shouldn't be modified by multiple threads

Answer (score 6):

From what you describe I assume your underlying problem may be caused by a race condition. Queues like lists use arrays internally and resize them when needed. They do it in powers of two, e.g. 128, 256 and 512, which coincidentally aligns with your count boundaries. Resizing means creating a new array (smaller or bigger) and copying the content to the new array, hands the `Array.Copy()` call.

From the Callstack I can see that the queue is resized during an `Enqueue` operation. Apparently in the mean-time the dequeue operation already shrunk the internal array causing the argument exception. Try using a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead and check again.

**Edit:** Link to latest documentation.

Comment: Better [linking to the new documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1)?

Comment: I tried concurrent queue as well. Got a similar error :  at (wrapper alloc) System.Object.AllocVector(intptr,intptr)
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[T]..ctor (System.Int32 boundedLength) [0x00006] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[T].EnqueueSlow (T item) [0x00051] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[T].Enqueue (T item) [0x00010] in <f56c876907e742b0aa586f051fcce845>:0

Comment: It's starting to get interesting. Can you add this (including exception message) to your original post plz?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the question. Thanks for replying

Comment: Can you include the exception type in your Stacktrace?